# Why is the node seminormal but the cusp not

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the notion of "seminormality" in scheme theory and In particular why the nodal curve $N=V(X^2=Y^2)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is seminormal but the cusp $C=V(X^2Z=Y^3)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is not.

First of all, I'll start with the definitions I've got:

$\textbf{Definition 1}:$
A reduced scheme $X$ is seminormal if for every reduced scheme $Y$, any bijective map $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ which induces isomorphisms on the level of residue fields $k(\pi(y))\rightarrow k(y)$ is an isomorphism.

$\textbf{Definition 2}:$ An integral domain is seminormal if for every $x,y\in R$ such that $x^2=y^3$ there exist $s\in R$ such that $s^3=x$ and $s^2=y$.

I have three questions:

$\textbf{Question 1}$: Is it true that a scheme $X$ is seminormal iff every stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is seminormal as a ring?

Going to the question in the title, I think I can see intuitively why the cusp $C$ is not seminormal: there is a map $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow C$ defined by $[1,y]\mapsto [y^2,y^3,1]$, $[0,1]\mapsto [0,1,0]$ which is bijective but is not an isomorphism. Instead for the nodal curve $N$ the map which sends $[1,y]$ to $[y^2,y^2,1]$ is not bijective, so I don't have to worry if it's an isomorphism or not. I also think I can understand the sense of Definition 2: given the point $[x,y,1]$ of $C$, $[1,s]$ would be the regular inverse.

$\textbf{Question 2}$: Is there a rigorous way to prove that $N$ is seminormal?

$\textbf{Question 3}$: Why is the condition on residue fields necessary? What is their role?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still of some interest to the OP, but perhaps it is useful to new readers, so here is an answer.

First off: Your definition of seminormal is incorrect. The morphism $\pi$ has to be finite. With your definition even a smooth curve would not be seminormal. (Take any curve $X$ and a closed point $P\in X$ and let $Y$ be the disjoint union of $X\setminus \{P\}$ and $\{P\}$ with the obvious bijection to $X$).

You can read about seminormality in a few places, although the references are scattered. A relatively recent and good place to start is Section 10.2 of [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/singularities-of-the-minimal-model-program/BFD87F262E5174A425F12AD85270E0AA).

To answer your questions:

Q1: Yes, that's true. In fact, sometimes that's taken as a definition. You can also see hints to why that's true in the above referenced book.

Q2: The proof that a cusp is not seminormal is exactly what you are saying. To see that a node is, let $X$ be a nodal curve and $\pi:Y\to X$ as in the definition (but finite!). Then the normalization of $Y$ is also the normalization of $X$. In other words, the normalization of $X$ factors through $Y$. That normalization is an isomorphism away from the node and at the node the module quotients of the local rings is a single copy of the base field. This means that anything in between is either isomorphic to $X$ or to its normalization. But the normalization is not bijective, so $Y$ cannot be isomorphic to that, so it is isomorphic to $X$.

Q3: Without the condition on the residue fields anything that admits a bijective endomorphism which is not an automorphism such as the Frobenius morphism in positive characteristics could not possibly be seminormal.